# Is it possible to dynamically generate a Discriminated Union in fsharp?

Tags: dynamic, f#, discriminated-union

I am looking into using `System.ComponentModel.Composition` in Fsharp and was wondering if it is possible to dynamically generate a Discriminated Union in memory? I would like to have DU that is built off elements of the types that are imported. The main reason is that I have code that works of a DU and I thought it most simple to use that with `Composition`. I am fully prepared to accept that this is the wrong thing to do.

I have used `FSharpType` and `FSharpValue` for various things in the past, but it seems that these are about manipulating existing DUs not creating new ones.

I am sorry to say I don't even yet have an 'I tried this' code sample because I don't know where to start.

- Is it possible?
- Is it advisable?
- Should I actually *not* be using a DU to represent what comes from Composition?
- I am happy to use reflection even though it is a bit slow.

*edit*

- Is it possible/advisable to dynamically add to a DU? (If a DU has to exist)

Comment: This sounds like a problem for type providers.

Comment: I am intrigued. A type provider of a `Composition`?

Comment: IMO a DU is useful when you get the compile-time checking and pattern matching going with it. If your data is so varied that it can take so many different types/representations, it sounds like a job for a type provider.

Comment: Interesting comment, rather than data my use case is extensibility with MEF. IE, there will be .dlls in a directory that will be brought in at run time. I am then using reflection to work with a DU. (It might be entirely the wrong thing to do :D )

Comment: I'd probably not recommend using it ;) but if you do want to generate DUs dynamically I have created a project http://fil.codeplex.com/ that does just that

Comment: Thanks Phillip. Very kind of you to point to this. I will avoid it as it goes down to IL - as I haven't learnt to fiddle that yet :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the big advantages of discriminated unions is that the set of possible cases is known at compile-time, so the compiler can tell you when your code doesn't handle a possible case. This helps a lot with refactoring as you can add a new case to an existing union and the compiler will tell you what places in the code need to be changed.

Another benefit is that pattern-matching on discriminated unions is syntactically elegant - you can write very clear code.

In theory you can probably dynamically generate a DU with Reflection.emit, or perhaps even add new cases to an existing one. However neither of the advantages above will apply so I don't really see much point in using them at all.

A standard inheritance model is also the right way to deal with dynamically loaded plugins, IMO. Define an interface or common base class in a DLL that each plugin depends on, have the plugin define a class that implements it, and then use methods on that interface/base class on the plugin once loaded.

DUs are designed to fix the set of possible /values/ in advance but make it easy for anyone to write a new function over the DU, whereas object-oriented inheritance is designed to fix the set of possible basic /functions/ in advance but make it easy for anyone to add new values. Since loading code dynamically is all about adding new values, I think it's a very natural fit.

It's worth mentioning in passing that DUs are actually implemented using .NET inheritance by the F# compiler - there's a base class for the entire union type, and then individual derived classes for each union case (though I think argument-less cases get treated specially).

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thanks for your answer. I have market this one as the answer because it shows how I was trying to do the wrong thing. Will move forward with a different pattern. :)